# A circle, a square, and an equilateral triangle had the same area. If their perimeters represent their ages, who are the oldest and the youngest?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

> Once upon a time, a circle, a square, and an equilateral triangle had the same area.
>
> If their perimeters represent their ages, who are the oldest and the youngest?
>
> Note: Perimeter of a circle is its circumference. Solve without a calculator.

Answer:
Let $s, r, x$ be the sidelength of the square, the radius of the circle, and the sidelength of the triangle, respectively.

$s^2 = \pi r^2 = x^2 \dfrac{ \sqrt{3}}{4}$

$s = r\sqrt{\pi} = x \sqrt{\dfrac{ \sqrt{3}}{4}} =  x {\dfrac{ \sqrt[4]{3}}{2}}$

Without using a calculator, still clearly, $s > r, s > x, x > r \Rightarrow s > x > r$.

But what I need is the comparison of $4s, 2\pi r,$ and $3x$.

Given $s > x,$ clearly $4s > 3s > 3x$.

editing this part below: it's still messy I'm on it right now.

Given $s > r$, clearly, $4s > 4r$,  $2 \pi r > 6r > 4r > 4s$.

Given $x > r,$ clearly, $$

okay, I can't seem to compare the others. I only know square's older than the triangle.

p.s. is it correct I tagged algebraic-geometry? lol

Comment: Welcome. No, algebraic geometry isn’t quite right!

Comment: Might be easier to set a s constant $A$ for area.  $s^2 = A$ so $s = \sqrt{A}$ and square is $4\sqrt{A}$ old.   $\pi r^2 = A$ so $r = \frac {\sqrt A}{\sqrt \pi}$ and so circle is $= 2\pi r = 2\sqrt \pi \sqrt A$. And $x^2 \frac {\sqrt 3}4 = A$ so $x = \sqrt A\frac 2{\sqrt[4]3}$ and so triangle is $\frac 6{\sqrt[4]{3}}\sqrt{A}$.  Just have to compare $4, 2\sqrt \pi$ and $\frac 6{\sqrt[4]{3}}$.

Comment: No reflection upon OP or any of the solution providers here, but I confess that I have problems with dressing up perfectly good mathematical truths in kindergarten language as an attempt to make such truths "relevant" or "interesting". Just sayin'.

Answer (score 5):

Just do it.

For the square we have:

Area = $A= s^2$.  So $s = \sqrt A$.
Age = perimeter = $4s$.  So Age= $4\sqrt{A}$.

For the circle we have:

Area = $A = \pi r^2$ so $r = \frac 1{\sqrt \pi} \sqrt A$.
Age = circumference = $2\pi r$. So Age = $2\pi\cdot \frac 1{\sqrt \pi}\sqrt A = 2\sqrt \pi \sqrt A$.

For the triangle we have

Area = $A =x^2 \frac {\sqrt 3}{4}$ so $x =\frac 2{\sqrt[4]3}\sqrt A$
Age = perimeter = $3x$. So Age $= 3\cdot \frac 2{\sqrt[4]3}\sqrt A$.

We need to compare: $4\sqrt{A},2\sqrt \pi \sqrt A, 3\cdot \frac 2{\sqrt[4]3}\sqrt A$.  So...

Just do it.

Divide all by $\sqrt A$ to compare

$4, 2\sqrt \pi, 3\cdot \frac 2{\sqrt[4]3}$

Divide all by $2$ to compare

$2, \sqrt \pi, \frac {3}{\sqrt[4]3}$.

Square each to compare

$4, \pi, \frac {9}{\sqrt 3}= 3\sqrt 3$.

$\pi < 4$.  And to compare $4$ to $3\sqrt 3$ we can square and compare $16$ to $9\times 3=27$.  So $4 < 3\sqrt 3$.

And that's that.  As $\pi < 4$ and $4 < 3\sqrt 3$ we know by transitivity that $\pi < 3\sqrt 3$.

So circle has the least circumference, then square, then triangle.

....

Now here's the thing.... you should start developing an intuition for these things and you will learn that we can maximize area of a shape with a given parameter by make the shape more circular. Eventually it should become intuitive that given the same parameters a regular triangle will have less area than a square which will have less area than a regular pentagon which will have less area than a hexagon and a circle will have the most area per perimeter.

And therefore if a circle, square and triangle have the same area it should be intuitive that the circle can achieve that area with the least circumference and the triangle will require the most perimeter.

However no-one is *born* with that intuition. But it is one all mathematicians eventually develop.  (And it comes from doing problems like these.)

Answer (score 3):

Given: $$s=r\sqrt{\pi}=x\cdot\frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{2}$$

Note that $4s=4r\sqrt{\pi}\gt2\pi r$ if and only if $2\gt\sqrt{\pi}$, by cross-dividing. However as $\pi\lt4$, this inequality is clear. Thus the square has larger perimeter than the circle.

$4s=4x\cdot\frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{2}\lt3x$ if and only if $\sqrt[4]{3}\lt\frac{3}{2}$, again by cross-dividing. This inequality is also true: can you see why?

So we conclude the square has a smaller perimeter than the triangle. The triangle is oldest and the circle is youngest.

PS I believe it is a general fact about (regular?) convex polyhedra that as the number of sides increases, the constant of proportionality (considered by continuous enlargements of the shape) of area $\propto$ perimeter will decrease.

Comment: Given $s > x,$ clearly $4s > 3s > 3x$.
so square's older than the triangle, right?

Comment: oh I made a mistake

Comment: my mistake: $s > x$

Comment: Just as a rougher or more-stretched-out 3D object will have a surface area : volume ratio higher than a spherical one, I believe you're correct about the last part, yes. In fact I seem to recall that no 2D object (of the same area) has a perimeter : area ratio smaller than a circle... but I don't know for certain nor have proof on hand.

Comment: @EricSnyder Me neither. It’s the kind of cute fact you could get taught in high school geometry without proof

Comment: Aha! Here is a WP link: [Isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality). Some of the references given, or searching for isoperimetric inequality elsewhere, turns up proofs, but they aren't as elementary as one might believe! (Note that it's also true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$, just substitute "circle" with "$n$-sphere.") (Non-elementary proofs as in "one uses Fourier analysis, another uses differential geometry, etc)

Comment: @EricSnyder Thanks! I’ve come across it before in measure theory but forgot all about it

Answer (score 0):

For a given area a circle has a *minimum* perimeter among all regular polygons found by methods of calculus of variations ( converse of iso-perimetric problem, can be termed iso-areal for changed objective/constraint) .

A Circle (radius $r$) has an *infinite number* of sides, $a\to 0$

Accordingly any regular polygon of same area of (side length $a$ )  has *more perimeter length* than the Circle. Perimeters (diminishing ages) are

For a "diangle" area $ \pi r^2, a \to (\infty \; r) $

For a triangle area $ \pi r^2 = \dfrac{\sqrt3}{4} a^2\to3 a\approx =8.08\; r$

For a square area $ \pi r^2  =4 a^2 \to 4a \approx 7.2 r\;$

For a Circle area $ \pi r^2  \text { minimum perimeter } a=2 \pi \approx 6.28 \;r.$